# Integrate a perturbation on a function

Tags: integration

I would like to approximate an integral for a function of the form:

$exp(-\int_0^a (\mu(\alpha) + b )d\alpha)$

where $\mu(\alpha)$ is an unknown function that is smooth, positively-valued function, and $b$ is a small positive constant. The slight twist that makes this integral potentially doable, is that I only need it in terms of:

$\bar{n} =\int_0^\infty exp(-\int_0^a \mu(\alpha) d\alpha) d a$

which is known. I have tried using a Taylor series on the integral, in terms of $b$ (centred on $b=0$) as as well as integrating by parts (the latter using differentiation under the integral sign) to try to get something that would look like:

$I= \int_0^\infty exp(-\int_0^a (\mu(\alpha) + b )d\alpha)d a\approx\bar{n}(1 - \eta(b))$

where $\eta(b)$ is a function of b. However neither of these paths seem to lead anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas here?

Best,

Ben

Comment: So $b$ is independent of $a$, right? Then the ``$b$ part" of the outer integral just becomes $\exp(-b a)$, and the whole thing becomes a Laplace transform. (Just spinning random ideas...)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Yep, $b$ is independent of $a$, so it comes out as you say...

Comment: .just not sure how to Laplace transform the thing, since $\mu(a)$ isn't known?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can. Where does this integral come from? It seems physicsy.

Comment: Good try! It's from mathematical biology here, and $\mu(a)$ is the force of mortality, and $b$ is an extra (constant) force of mortality due to an external phenomena.

Comment: If we take the last approximate equality in your post literally, then we find that $\eta(b) = b <a> + O(b^2)$, where $<a>$ is the average of $a$ under the probability density function $\exp(-\int_0^a d\alpha\, \mu(\alpha)) / \bar{n}$.